# Cut through plaster vaneer

Tags: drywall, plaster

My house was built in the 50s and has the same wall construction described here: [Is this plaster over gypsum wallboard?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/145909/is-this-plaster-over-gypsum-wallboard/176707#176707?newreg=0c1e9a36c5984fe39052e0850d4426b7)

Does anyone know how I can easily cut through it.  I've been using my sturdy drywall saw, which works, but is slow and arduous.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I use a sawzall a reciprocating saw with a wood bit and it goes through it like butter. Check for live voltage behind the area you want to cut or you may have some wires to repair , yup done that more than once.
I lay the tip lightly on the surface handle and blade touching the wall. Start the saw holding the front of the saw still wile lifting the handle away from the surface, once through hold the saw at a 90 and cut away.
I have seen a jigsaw used he drilled a hole big enough for the blade it was a bit slower but a nice reusable cut.